# My 30lb Catahoula ripped open a pack of instant yeast

Tags: dogs, health, training, safety, medicines

My 11-month-old Catahoula pit ripped open a pack of dry instant sourdough yeast. I got the packet before he ingested any of it but I think a small amount definitely got in his tongue. Should I be concerned? He hasn't thrown up and he's not acting drunk or any different than usual.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should most likely be fine.

Yeast can be everywhere. Yeast is everywhere. If some old fruits or bread go bad it's very possible yeast is involved, too. So your dog will inevitably eat or inhale tiny amounts of different cultures all the time anyway.

Second, a dog's stomach acid is very aggressive, way more aggressive than that of humans. The smaller the amounts of yeast are, the less likely any would survive for long.

Last but not least, yeast requires some form of carbohydrates or sugars to grow significantly. As long as you don't feed any amount of sugars (might be included in some dog treats), it will simply starve to death while being digested.

With these points in mind, I'd say the chances of any health complications are rather slim and next to impossible.

Eating a pile of dough (which would include "food" for the yeast and more mass/volume to somewhat protect from acid) would be way worse, but also depending on the amount, likely harmless.

In fact, my dog stole a significant piece of fresh pizza dough as a puppy with basically no effects.

Just keep an eye on your dog and contact your vet in case there's any abnormal behavior the next 1-2 days, but I really wouldn't worry too much about this.